# Modern sources on Lie algebraic methods in combinatorics

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am looking for modern textbooks, expository papers and journal articles regarding the use of Lie algebras in combinatorics. In particular, I am interested to know the extent to which people still care about this.

For example, the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{C})$ can be used to show that certain sequences are unimodal and symmetric. This and similar material can be found in Richard Stanley's [papers](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/) (e.g. 41, 57, 62, 72, 84).

In the textbooks I've looked at (e.g. Aigner's *A Course in Enumeration*, Stanley's EC1/2) you can find material on things like posets, Young tableaux, and the character theory of $S_n$ and $\mathrm{GL}(n)$. But it seems like Lie algebras such as $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{C})$ have been left out.

Comment: Modern literature on crystals should be of help. [Mark Shimozono, *Crystals for dummies*](http://www.aimath.org/WWN/kostka/crysdumb.pdf) does a lot of tableau combinatorics based on using the theory of crystal bases as a black box, which he gives references for. As far as I understand, at least the majority of these references uses Lie-algebraic methods to prove things.

Comment: Also, there are some partition identities that are proven using vertex algebras (if you count those as Lie-algebraic methods); random google hit: [Debajyoti Nandi's thesis](https://rucore.libraries.rutgers.edu/rutgers-lib/45379/). Someone who actually understands vertex algebras could tell much more...

Comment: More google hits: [Mirko Primc, *Vertex Algebras and Combinatorial Identities*](http://link.springer.com.ololo.sci-hub.ac/article/10.1023/A:1019747408807) and [S. Capparelli, *On Some Representations of Twisted Affine Lie Algebras and Combinatorial Identities*](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1993.1017).

Comment: @Darij These are excellent, thank you! If it's not too much trouble, could you compile this into an answer?

Comment: @TGunn: Done below.

Comment: "Recent developments (including some open problems)": [Combinatorial representation theory of Lie algebras. Richard Stanley's work and the way it was continued](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0352).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- A lot of the literature on crystals (in the modern sense of algebraic combinatorics) uses the theory of crystal bases (which is part of quantum group theory) as a black box. For one example of such a use, see [Mark Shimozono, *Crystals for dummies*](http://www.aimath.org/WWN/kostka/crysdumb.pdf), which proves various properties of semistandard Young tableaux using crystals.
- Vertex algebras can be used to prove partition identities. For example: [Debajyoti Nandi, *Partition identities arising from the standard $A_2^{(2)}$-modules of level $4$*, thesis](https://rucore.libraries.rutgers.edu/rutgers-lib/45379/) or [Mirko Primc, *Vertex Algebras and Combinatorial Identities*](http://link.springer.com.ololo.sci-hub.ac/article/10.1023/A:1019747408807) and [S. Capparelli, *On Some Representations of Twisted Affine Lie Algebras and Combinatorial Identities*](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1993.1017). Do you count vertex algebras as part of Lie-algebra theory?
- [Jean-Louis Loday, Todor Popov, *Parastatistics Algebra, Young Tableaux and the Super Plactic Monoid*](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~loday/PAPERS/2008LodayPopov%28Parastat%29.pdf) obtains a generalized Cauchy identity for hook Schur functions (a super-version of Schur functions) from representations of Lie superalgebras.